# Call a decorator function from its inner class

Tags: java, decorator

I have a class P with two methods, a() and b(). Also I have a decorator for class P named decoratorP that extends the P class (they're not in the same file either). Inside this decorator, I also have those two methods with a couple of additional operations.

When I get the instance of decoratorP (lets say, from the main), I call decoratorP.a(). So, those additional operations are executed and then I proceed to execute the P.a() function. Case is that, at the end of P.a(), I need to execute decoratorP.b() function, and I need to call it from the P class instance (I cannot do it from the main). Is there any possibility to do so?

I don't know how to accomplish this maintaining the decorator pattern.

Comment: Why can't `decoratorP.a()` not just call `delegate.a()` followed by `delegate.b()`? (Assuming your decorator is a real decorator with a delegate and doesn't just call `super.a()`, in which case it wouldn't be much of a decorator, but the same question/suggestion would still apply).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.